# How to run AutoCAD LT 2002 as a non-Administrator user?

Tags: windows-xp, permissions, windows-registry, autocad

When I launch AutoCAD LT 2002 as a non-Administrator user, it displays the error message `You do not have sufficient rights to run AutoCAD LT` and then quits.

I also tried running it as Administrator once, in case it needed to perform some post-installation configuration.  Now, when I log in as a non-Administrator user, it says `Failed to update the system registry.  Please try using REGEDIT.` and runs.  But it would be nice to quell that error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Log in as Administrator
- Launch `REGEDT32.EXE`
- For each of the following registry keys, recursively grant full permissions for the non-Administrator user:

  - `HKCR\AutoCAD.Drawing.15`
  - `HKCR\AutoCAD LT.Drawing`
  - `HKCR\CLSID\{4D3263E4...`
  - `HKCU\Software\Autodesk`
  - `HKLM\Software\Autodesk`